# Jquery Onclick Function not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery

html form-

```
<div class="inner-container login-panel id="login_form"">
  <h3 class="m_title">SIGN IN YOUR ACCOUNT TO HAVE ACCESS TO DIFFERENT FEATURES</h3>
  <div id="login_form" class="loginform">
    <a href="#" class="create_account" onClick="ppOpen('#register_panel', '280');">CREATE ACCOUNT</a>
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="inputbox" placeholder="Email">
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="inputbox" placeholder="Password">
    <button  id="loginsubmit" class="btn btn-red">LOG IN</button>
    <a href="#" class="login_facebook">login with facebook</a>
  </div>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="#" onClick="ppOpen('#forgot_panel', '350');">FORGOT YOUR USERNAME?</a> / <a href="#" onClick="ppOpen('#forgot_panel', '350');">FORGOT YOUR PASSWORD?</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

And javascript code -

```
 console.log("before");
 $(document).ready(function (){
    console.log("then");
    $("#loginsubmit").click(function (){
        console.log("success");
        e = $("#email").val();
        p = $("#pass").val();
        if($("#email").val()==""||$("#pass").val()==""){
            $("div#ack").html("please enter email and pass");
           }
        else {
            $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
                    //$("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
                    {emailid: e, password: p},
                    function(data){
                        $("div#ack").html(data);
                    });
             }       
        $("#myForm").submit( function(){
            return false;
        });
     });
 });
```

In the console before and then is printing but no response on clicking `#loginsubmit` . Is there any problem with the javascript code? Please help me to find it out.

Comment: use curly braces when you use if...else condition for multiple line of code.

Comment: Edited. Still no response.

Comment: do you getting success on console..?

Comment: no. that is the problem.

Comment: Bhojendra Nepal : even before the edit, there was no multiple code lines in the if...else block

Comment: I tried it as follows                                                                                         <a  id="loginsubmit" class="btn btn-red">LOGIN</a>      $(document).ready(function (){
$("#loginsubmit").click(function (){
        console.log("success");});
}); and is giving success on console

Comment: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6phuxdor/) `success` is printing in `console.log()`

Comment: Your code is working I copied your whole code and run it on jsfiddle..it's printing success in console

Comment: It's working as well for me... Could you please remove all unnecessary code to make your question more readable? Maybe it could even let you find the problem by yourself.

Comment: Is it a `jquery` library inclusion problem?. The serial is `html` , `jquery lib`, `customjs`..

Comment: Uploaded it http://dsbangladesh.com/ please check by clicking login button.

Comment: can you try getting click event like this......                           $(document).on('click', '#loginsubmit', function () {
console.log("success");
});

Comment: Solved it by creating a custom function.

Comment: Please share your solution?

Comment: Added in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working you have not written div element with #ack id , , If will add this element you can see the responce on button click.

Answer (score 0):

html : `<button  id="loginsubmit" class="btn btn-red" onclick="logincheck()">LOG IN</button>`

Javascript:

```
function logincheck(){
    console.log("success");
    e = $("#email").val();
    p = $("#pass").val();
    if($("#email").val()==""||$("#pass").val()=="")
        $("div#ack").html("please enter email and pass");
    else
        $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
                //$("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
                {emailid: e, password: p},
                function(data){
                    $("div#ack").html(data);
                });
    $("#myForm").submit( function(){
        return false;
    });

}
```

Now it is working properly.

Answer (score -2):

kindly use following updated script and html:

javascript:

```
console.log("before");
$(document).ready(function (){    
    console.log("then");
    $("#loginsubmit").click(function (){
        console.log("success");
        e = $("#email").val();
        p = $("#pass").val();
        if($("#email").val()==""||$("#pass").val()==""){
            $("div#ack").html("please enter email and pass");
        }
        else {
            $.post( $("#myForm").attr("action"), 
            //$("#myForm :input").serializeArray(),
            { emailid:e, password:p },
                function(data){
                    $("div#ack").html(data);
                },'json');
            }       
            $("#myForm").submit( function(){
                return false;
            });
        });
});
```

Html:

```
<div class="inner-container login-panel id="login_form"">    
    <h3 class="m_title">SIGN IN YOUR ACCOUNT TO HAVE ACCESS TO DIFFERENT FEATURES</h3>
    <form action="#" method="post" id="myForm">
        <div id="login_form" class="loginform">
            <a href="#" class="create_account" onClick="ppOpen('#register_panel', '280');">CREATE ACCOUNT</a>
            <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="inputbox" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" class="inputbox" placeholder="Password">
            <button  id="loginsubmit" class="btn btn-red">LOG IN</button>
            <a href="#" class="login_facebook">login with facebook</a>
            <div id="ack"></div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div class="links">
        <a href="#" onClick="ppOpen('#forgot_panel', '350');">FORGOT YOUR USERNAME?</a> / 
        <a href="#" onClick="ppOpen('#forgot_panel', '350');">FORGOT YOUR PASSWORD?</a>
    </div>
</div>
```